# parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets) - Haskell problem with main declaration

Tags: haskell

This is my code

```
root::(Integer,Integer)->Integer
root guess number   | (guess*guess == number ) =guess
                    | root (guess+number/guess)/2 number
main::IO()
main = {print(root 1,4)}
```

I keep getting parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets) even if I don't mention the print statement inside braces. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, you seem to have some confusion regarding declaring and passing parameters.

One can generally distinguish two ways (two "traditions" if you will) of passing parameters - "tupled form" and "curried form".

The former - "tupled form" - is passing all parameters together in a tuple:

```
-- Function declaration
root :: (Integer, Integer) -> Integer
root (guess, number) = ...

-- Calling the function
x = root (1, 4)
```

A tuple is denoted with parentheses and separating commas. Here, the type of parameters is a tuple - `(Integer, Integer)`, - and the formal parameters are matched as a tuple - `(guess, number)`, - and when calling the function I'm passing them as a tuple - `(1, 4)`. Same syntax in all three cases.

Technically, this function has only *one* parameter, not two. And that one parameter is of tuple type.

The latter - "curried form" - is passing parameters "one by one", so to say:

```
-- Function declaration
root :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
root guess number = ...

-- Calling the function
x = root 1 4
```

Here, the parameter types are declared separately in curried form - `Integer -> Integer ->`, - and the parameters are matched in a curried form - `guess number = ...`, - and when calling the function they are also passed in curried form - `1 4`.

---

In your code, however, there seems to be a mishmash of these two styles:

- The type of `root` says the parameters are tupled - `(Integer, Integer)`
- The body of `root` says they are curried - `root guess number`
- And the call site is sort of a half-tuple - there is a comma, but no parentheses.

Choose one style and follow it in all three places.

---

**Second**, the two cases in the body of `root` are malformed. Each case must have a form `| <condition> = <body>`. In your first case you have a condition `(guess*guess == number)` and a body `guess`, but in your second case there is only one part (there is no equality sign).

From the semantics, I would venture a *guess* that your second case was meant to be "otherwise" - i.e. it was meant to be evaluated if the first case's condition didn't match.

If that is correct, just add `otherwise` as condition:

```
                | (guess*guess == number) = guess
                | otherwise = root (guess+number/guess)/2 number
```

Comment: `root (guess+number/guess)/2 number` parses as `(root (guess+number/guess)) / (2 number)`, so a few more parentheses are needed. (+1)